# React Stripe Elements - set width to auto for iFrame? Elements invisible inside grid and modal

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to build a Stripe form using React Elements, inside of a React Modal, with layout managed by React Grid

```
<StripeProvider apiKey="stripeApiKey">
    <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justify="center"
        style={{ minWidth: '30rem', maxWidth: '100rem' }}
    >
        <Grid item>
            <Grid
                container
                direction="column"
                justify="center"
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
                    padding: '73px',
                    width: '100%'
                }}
            >
                <Elements>
                    <CardElement />
                </Elements>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</StripeProvider>
```

The above renders the CardElement, but it's set to 1px width. If I manually set the IFrame's width property to auto it completely resolves my problem. How can I set the IFrame's width property for Stripe? (or is this even possible with cross-origin IFrame)

Or if not, how else can I resolve this issue to get the fields to display?

[image: poorly displayed modal]
[image: changing iframe width]
[image: correctly displayed modal after manually adjusting width]

Answer (score 0):

The style for individual elements for React-Stripe has to be passed manually as props. Below is an example from their official react-stripe-elements sample:

Elements

```
<CardNumberElement
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        onFocus={handleFocus}
                        onReady={handleReady}
                        {...createOptions(this.props.fontSize)}
                    />
```

Function createOptions

```
const createOptions = (fontSize, padding) => {
    return {
        style: {
            base: {
                fontSize,
                color: '#424770',
                letterSpacing: '0.025em',
                fontFamily: 'Source Code Pro, monospace',
                '::placeholder': {
                    color: '#aab7c4',
                },
                ...(padding ? { padding } : {}),
            },
            invalid: {
                color: '#9e2146',
            },
        },
    };
};
```

css

```
    input,
    .StripeElement {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 10px 14px;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
      box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0196078) 0px 1px 0px;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background: white;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working in my case. I have tried your suggestion setting both width and height to no avail

Comment: Try passing in the following css as well? It also comes from the offical example:    input,
    .StripeElement {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 10px 14px;
      font-size: 1em;
      font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
      box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.14902) 0px 1px 3px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0196078) 0px 1px 0px;
      border: 0;
      outline: 0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      background: white;
    }